# Cannot cast java.lang.Float to float when using Class.cast?

Tags: java, class, casting

I already have a solution, but I don't like it. Also, it would be nice to know your thoughts about this.

You see, `elem.get` gives back an `Object`, that is going to be a `Float` in the case of x and y.

This code throws the Exception described in the title:

```
String names[] = { "x", "y", "src" };
Class types[] = { float.class, float.class, String.class };

for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++)
{
    if (elem.containsKey(names[i]))
    {
        par.add(types[i]);
        arg.add(types[i].cast(elem.get(names[i])));
    }
}
```

The code is used to define the list of parameters to instantiate an object. Both the parameters and the object's class name are defined in an external data file (but nevermind about that).

The solution, something I'm not fond of (because it loses the flexibility I was trying to attain), has this within the for:

```
if(types[i] == float.class)
{
    float v = (Float)elem.get(names[i]);
    arg.add(v);
} else
{
    arg.add(types[i].cast(elem.get(names[i])));
    break;
}
```

Other option would be changing `float.class` to `Float.class` in `types`, but I won't do that because that code is used to instantiate objects which have `float` parameters in their constructors.

Thanks!

Comment: If you're using java 1.5 or higher, Floats will be auto-unboxed to floats, no?  Did you try using Float.class?

Comment: As I wrote, I don't want to use Float.class, because I need the argument to be used as a float in the instantiation that I do afterwards. But if I use Float.class in this code, it works. It just fails later when trying to instantiate the Object which constructor has floats. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the type of `args` is an `ArrayList<Object>`, you're not avoiding the boxing anyway:

```
// This code...
float v = (Float)elem.get(names[i]);
arg.add(v);

// Will actually be equivalent to:
float v = (Float)elem.get(names[i]);
Float boxed = v;
arg.add(boxed);
```

If the point is to call a constructor by reflection, then you're going to *have* to pass in a `Float` for any `float` parameters - that's just how it works.

So basically, change `float.class` to `Float.class` and it should all work fine. EDIT: Ah, except then the `par` list will have the wrong type. Basically you want to *cast* with `Float.class`, but *add* `float.class` to the list of parameter types.

You probably want a map from primitive types to wrapper types, like this:

```
private static final Map<Class<?>>, Class<?>> PRIMITIVE_TYPE_MAP =
    buildPrimitiveTypeMap();

private static Map<Class<?>>, Class<?>> buildPrimitiveTypeMap()
{
    Map<Class<?>>, Class<?>> map = new HashMap<Class<?>>, Class<?>>();
    map.put(float.class, Float.class);
    map.put(double.class, Double.class);
    // etc
    return map;
}
```

Then:

```
String names[] = { "x", "y", "src" };
Class types[] = { float.class, float.class, String.class };

for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++)
{
    if (elem.containsKey(names[i]))
    {
        par.add(types[i]);

        // For primitive types, only box to the wrapper type
        Class<?> castType = PRIMITIVE_TYPE_MAP.get(types[i]);
        if (castType == null)
        {
            castType = types[i];
        }
        arg.add(castType.cast(elem.get(names[i])));
    }
}
```

---

In fact, if you trust that the values are of the right type already, I suspect you can just do:

```
arg.add(elem.get(names[i]));
```

After all, you're just casting to a particular type and then losing that type information again... using the `cast` call does perform a check that the execution-time types are correct though, so you may want to keep it for that reason.

Comment: Oops. Sorry. arg is a ArrayList<Object>.

Comment: @huff: Right, so as I thought - when you add a `float` to it, it'll be boxed to `Float` anyway. Will edit my answer to make that clearer.

Comment: Thanks! So, but when I use Float.class it doesn't find the proper constructor for the object to instantiate.

Comment: (say that the object Example has a constructor Example(float x, float y))

Comment: @huff: Ah - possibly because of the `par.add(types[i]);` part. Will edit for that...

Comment: (and imagine that there are many many classes to change, or that I can't touch the Example class)

Comment: @huff: Have edited. It's slightly awkward - it would be nice if `Class` had a `getWrapperClass` method which return null for non-primitive types :( If you can trust the original data, you don't need to do the cast at all of course, which avoids the problem :)

Comment: What about... is there any way to figure float.class from Float.class? I mean, like a way to get back the primitive (if that is the proper term). Like using Float.class, but then par.add(types[i].primitive())

Comment: @huff: You should go the other way: given `float.class` (the "correct" parameter type) you want to keep that information for the parameter types, but go to the wrapper type for the cast call. Otherwise you'll have a problem with any constructors which genuinely have a `Float` parameter.

Comment: Ok! I have seen the Map solution. I hoped there was some easiest way, but thanks!!